# How can I import multiple components from react-bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to build a dropdown menu, so I import both `DropdownButton` and `MenuItem`.

```
import { DropdownButton } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { MenuItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

However, I see the following error:

```
error  'react-bootstrap' import is duplicated  no-duplicate-imports
```

How do I import both components from react-bootstrap?

Comment: `import { DropdownButton, MenuItem } from 'react-bootstrap';`

Answer (score 9):

Combine the import into one line:

```
import { DropdownButton, MenuItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

Comment: Do you know how to import all from react-bootstrap. I get an error when trying to import * as ReactBootstrap from 'react-bootstrap'